# What mass of pure ice would be melted by 1kg of salt at a given temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, ice

Salt melts ice by disrupting the molecular bonds of the lattice, producing salty water (brine). But brine has its own freezing point. If the brine gets too cold, it begins to form ice, and the remaining brine becomes saltier, which drops its freezing point. This establishes an equilibrium. I have access to the relationship between brine freezing point and salinity.

If I had a large quantity of ice at a subzero temperature $T$ and added $m_s$ of salt, the salt would melt an amount of ice, $m_i$, and form brine. The brine would initially be very concentrated, but would gradually become more and more diluted as more ice melts until its freezing point reaches the ambient temperature, T. At this point, no more ice could be melted by the brine.

Is there a commonly accepted formula relating $m_i, m_s$ and $T$? Can I get it out of the equation that links the brine freezing point to the salinity?

I'm happy to ignore latent heat fluxes due to melting and freezing.

Comment: You can't ignore latent heat.

Comment: You can ignore it if you hold the system's temperature constant and look for the long-term response (i.e. attach to reservoir).

Comment: I see. In that case, I don't see how this question is well defined: In the long run, you would expect an equilibrium where the salt is uniformly distributed, and then either everything is frozen or everything is melted.  Can you make your question more clear?